# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los "elementos" de Polymer y las "directivas" de AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

En la página de Polymer [Getting Started](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/usingelements.html), podemos ver un ejempo de Polymer funcionando:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- 1. Shim missing platform features -->
    <script src="polymer-all/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Load a component -->
    <link rel="import" href="x-foo.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- 3. Declare the component by its tag. -->
    <x-foo></x-foo>
  </body>
</html>
```

Date cuenta de que `<x-foo></x-foo>` viene definido por `platform.js` y por `x-foo.html`.

Parece que esto es equivalente a la directiva de un modulo de AngularJS:

```
angular.module('xfoo', [])
.controller('X-Foo', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'hey hey!';
})
.directive('x-foo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        controller: 'X-Foo',
        templateUrl: '/views/x-foo.html',
        link: function(scope, controller) {
        }
    };
});
```

- ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los dos?
- ¿Que problemas soluciona Polymer que no haya solucionado AngularJS ?
- ¿Existe algún plan para unir Polymer con AngularJS en el futuro?

> Pregunta original: [What is the difference between Polymer elements and AngularJS directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089075/what-is-the-difference-between-polymer-elements-and-angularjs-directives)

Answer (score 2):

Hay bastantes diferencias, bien importantes, primero que todo AngularJS es un framework y Polymer es solo una librería; en AngularJS tienes muchísimas cosas más que solo directivas, hay modelos, rutas, web requests, promesas, etc, lo que te permite crear aplicaciones complejas.

Polymer sirve para crear web components. Web Components son un nuevo estándar para la web, en el futuro se espera que todos los navegadores lo implementen y seán usados por los desarrolladores, pero por ahora se necesitan herramientas como Polymer para simular estas funcionalidades. Angular no ha intentado solucionar esto, ni tiene planes para hacerlo, aunque en el futuro cuando Web Components sea prevalente es probable que Angular les saque provecho.

No existe ningun plan para unirlos, pero los equipos se mantienen en contacto y el equipo de Angular ha expresado interés en usar Polymer para algunos widgets.